# What can I do to solve the "Cannot find module './util/UnsubscriptionError'"?

Tags: angular

Am a total beginner in js...

I followed the tutorial code and tried localhost in an Angular project.
Suddenly it complains that the module cannot be found. (was working fine)

[image]

but I can allocate the file within the build pack for the project.
[image]

Is there something I can do to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the code where you import this? and your file structure?

Comment: what do you want to do, do you just serve?
if you use --open, Open the URL in the default browser.